# How to send/share custom data to FB when a user Like a post on a posts page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, customization

Consider a page with many posts as:

```
Page A
  - post 1
  - post 2
  - post 3
  - ...
```

Is it possible to add a Like button for each post (1, 2, 3, ...) and when a user "Like" one of them, **send/share the information of that post** on Facebook?

For each post I wan to share the title, description, photo, ...

I can't use Open Graph meta data because it's page related, right?

Thank you for you answers, I'm stuck.

Comment: Are these posts have different urls or not? Can they opened t different url?

Comment: Well, in my case we can consider that the post is not available by its own. But I understand your point here: if I add a page for each post, then I can add the unique url to each post in the Like button and therefore use Open Graph meta data. Right?

Comment: yes... use Open Graph meta data

Answer (score 1):

As long as each post has its own unique URL with Facebook metadata on it, yes you can.

Each like button has to have a reference to the respective page.

Comment: Okay, I've answered to Somnath Muluk comment a few minutes ago. I understand now how Facebook retrieve the informations. The problem I still have is that I need to share the post information but I also want to set the url to the "Page A", not the "post".

Comment: If you set the URL to "Page A" you'll get "Page A's" metadata when you share the post. If you want the user to end up on "Page A" when you follow the link to "post 1", make a unique url for "post 1" with metadata, and a javascript redirect to Page A. Facebook will get the correct data, and a visiting user will end up where you want them.

Comment: Could work indeed, but as I've written in a comment: I've changed my mind and my app. I upvote your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just make the like button URL something like http://www.yourblog.com/pages/A?title=post1&description=blah&image=baz.png

Then in your site/blog you need to take the query data from the URL and add that into your meta data dynamically*, i.e.

```
<meta type="og:title" content={GET['title']} />
<meta type="og:description" content={GET['description']} />
<meta type="og:image" content={GET['image']} />
```

(this is pseudo code)

*Technically you only need to do this when the User Agent is the Facebook scraper, but you may as well do it always unless there's a strong reason not to. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/ for more information.

Comment: Nice way to do it, but I've not tested your solution. I've just change d my app to be more in the FB standards. I upvote your answer even if it's not the solution I had expected.